# indian languages in my android studio showing in blank spaces

Tags: android-studio

In android studio the indian languages are displaying as blank spaces,  how to resolve it.

```
<string name="lang_hindi">    </string>
<string name="lang_kannada">    </string>
<string name="lang_tamil">    </string>
<string name="lang_oriya">    </string>
<string name="lang_bengali">    </string>
```

Comment: its showing blank beceause it is a blank. Add your text inside string brackets.              `<string name="lang_hindi"> lang hindi </string>`

Comment: when i copy here the languages are appearing, so i removed here to show how its look like